# while exporting 35,000 records in excel format using SSRS , it takes too much time(20mins) to export

Tags: ssrs-2012

SSRS - Excel export time delay

I am expecting that my report to be exported within 10 seconds. I have tried adding a parent group to the Tablix by referring the link: "https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3552/handle-excel-exceeds-maximum-65536-rows-in-ssrs-2008r2/". But it seems to be not working. Can someone please come up with a solution for my problem facing in SSRS export.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Try using CSV file format instead of excel files.

Comment: Thanks @UtkarshDubey .... the CSV file format is exporting fast. But I need in Excel format is there any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answers your question, here are some solutions which you can try,

Reference: [SSRS Export to Excel - Performance](http://thesqldeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/04/ssrs-export-to-excel-performance.html)

As per this blog,

> So, when the report is rendered using Excel renderer, the columns were merged to accommodate the differing column widths. I went ahead and managed to reduce the merged columns from around 5 to 1 (This would be much harder for Matrix reports). Surprisingly, this solved the issue - the size of the exported Excel file went down to < 4 MB and the report now opens in < 1 min.

Key issues areas where you need to check,

1. I've already added CSV file solution in the comment section.
2. Check how many merged columns do you have in your report.
3. Check if you have mentioned page breaks or not in your report. If not, then use it.
4. Do you have drilldown or other links in the report? This may blow up the size of Excel.
5. Try checking SSRS server logs they may have any specific information about this performance issue.

Other References: [Export to Excel takes long time in SSRS 2008](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/124d54f4-583c-4d6d-ac93-4a8e2971b438/export-to-excel-takes-long-time-in-ssrs-2008?forum=sqlreportingservices)

**Update**

- Did you also check indexing in the database because I am able to export more than 65000 records in a less than 1 minute.
- Do you have latest service pack installed? [KB2963388 - FIX: SSRS 2012 cannot export a report that is larger than 10 MB to Excel format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb2963388-fix-ssrs-2012-cannot-export-a-report-that-is-larger-than-10-mb-to-excel-format-1ed1976d-78d1-e1f3-e24e-f6b7bab733fc)